# How to perform enable/disbale or hide/unhide in asp.net mvc 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, view, viewdata

I am passing some viewdata and view bag to the view through controller , below is the snippet of the code:

```
IProductRepository prodResp = new ProductRepository();
        Product getGarages = prodResp.GetDetailsForGarages((int)Session["EventID"]);
        Product getHelmets = prodResp.GetDetailsForHelmet((int)Session["EventID"]);
        if (getGarages == null)
        {

            ViewBag.Garages = null;
        }
            ViewBag.Garages = getGarages;
            int totalGarages = getGarages.QtyAvailable;
            var garages = Enumerable.Range(1, totalGarages).Select(x => new SelectListItem { Value = x.ToString(), Text = x.ToString() });
            ViewBag.GaragesDropDown = new SelectList(garages.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

            if (getHelmets == null)
            {
                ViewBag.helmets = null;
            }
            ViewBag.helmets = getHelmets;
        return View(booking);
    }
```

View

```
<% if (Convert.ToBoolean(ViewBag.boolSecondDriver))
                      {%>

                    <lable>Second Driver Availablity For this Event</lable><br />
                   <lable>Secondriver:</lable> <%: Html.TextBox("SecondDriver") %>
                    <br />
                   <lable>SecondriverPrice:</lable> <%: ViewBag.trackday.SecondDriverPrice %>
                    <br /><br />

                    <lable>Number of Helmets Available For this Event</lable><br /><br />
                    <lable>No of Helmets:</lable><%: ViewBag.helmets.QtyAvailable%><br />
                    <lable>Price per unit:</lable><%: ViewBag.helmets.UnitCost%> <br /><br />

                    <lable>Number of Garages Available For this Event</lable><br /><br />
                   <lable>No of Garages:</lable> <%: ViewBag.Garages.QtyAvailable%><br />
                    <lable>price per unit:</lable><%: ViewBag.Garages.UnitCost%>

                     <%}
                       else{ %> 


                      <lable>Second Driver Availablity For this Event</lable><br />
                   <lable>Free</lable>

                    <br /><br />

                    <lable>Number of Helmets Available For this Event</lable><br /><br />
                    <lable>No of Helmets:</lable><%: ViewBag.helmets.QtyAvailable%><br />
                    <lable>Price per unit:</lable><%: ViewBag.helmets.UnitCost%> <br /><br />

                    <lable>Number of Garages Available For this Event</lable><br /><br />
                   <lable>No of Garages:</lable> <%: ViewBag.Garages.QtyAvailable%><br />
                    <lable>price per unit:</lable><%: ViewBag.Garages.UnitCost%>

                      <%} %>
```

The issue I am having is I cant hide or unhide the Viewbag if the value of viewbag.value is null then the respected viewbag.values should be hidden in the view , therefore I am getting errors: Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference.  Any suggestions or alternatives will be highly appreciated thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any suggestions or alternatives will be highly appreciated thanx.

Have you considered using a **ViewModel**?

ViewBag is fine when dealing with single fields etc that don't warrant a "model", but you have a lot of code there, i see nouns like *Helmet* and *Garage* - so you should be using a ViewModel.

Then you can use:

```
<%: Html.DisplayFor(model => model.SecondDriver) %>
```

And if `SecondDriver` is null nothing will be rendered.

And you can create a display template for whatever type `SecondDriver` is, and move the markup there, meaning you can re-use it across any Views.

Don't know about you, but when i do MVC development, my #1 goal is to keep my View clean and free from code soup - which is what you currently have.

Comment: I guess you are right , the problem is i m populating this view using 2-3 tables . And the view model for this view doesnt contains all the entity properties of other models although they are associated through foreign key with each other, The neat solution can be like build a parent model and attach the sub models in it .. something like this I guess ..

Comment: I was quite comfortable with webforms using the hidden and enable property of the user controls , but struggling with mvc , may be i have limited skills or you can say exposure to mvc yet and finding it hard to resolve basic issues.

Comment: @Muhammad - you'll get there, don't worry mate. WebForms has poisoned us all, the anecdote is read, learn, code, and explore. You should create a ViewModel with everything your View needs, including parent/child, e.g nested view models. Our team often codes the View first, with hardcoded HTML, then we know what ViewModel to create, so we create it, then do the controller to populate it from the model.

Comment: 1984 .. Thnx mate, will work on new view models on odar pages, I lyk your point of creating view first , coz that makes it clear what one really wants on the page , but in real time , you know the clients they come up with different stuff every next morning , which makes life hard .. You can't expect to get d xact view at all.. its a continuous refactoring process, What I was thinking is it a good idea to create parent models for all the view pages and then add the different models in it depending on the requirements.

Comment: Have you got any examples of a view using multiple entity models . Or you can say a model with multiple entity models in it which can be used by view for intellisense

Answer (score 1):

You could add another property to the `ViewBag`:

```
ViewBag.MyStuffIsNull = (MyStuff == null);
```

Then in your view you can use this property to test for null:

```
<% if (ViewBag.MyStuffIsNull) { %>
    // Do work
<% } %>
```

Comment: why are you using @ before if .

Comment: but there will be too many if statements ..is there ny cleaner solution to it